# Regex which recognizes single expressions

Tags: regex

So I need a RegEx which recognizes a housenumber with 1 to 3 numbers and an optional letter.

Correct: `4,5A,471c`

Wrong: `0, A, 4711c`

What I already got: `\d,\d[A-Z],[a-z]`

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: No I know what to do but I have this not working solution: \d,\d[A-Z],[a-z]

Comment: You can try this: ^[1-9]\d{0,2}[A-Za-z]?$

Comment: @PoulBak Do you know a solution for this 1nbif-1 bis 5nbbgM-36. I would really appreciate if you can help me one more time. Thanks!

Comment: @PoulBak Feel free to write the answer.